# macOS "Verifying Microsoft [Excel/Word/Powerpoint].app" over and over again

Tags: macos, ms-office, big-sur

Here's the problem I'm having with Microsoft Office apps:

[image]

I see this dialog several times a month when I launch Microsoft Word/Excel/Powerpoint.

Very frequently, the verification process hangs, and I need to force-quit.

Even when it succeeds, it often takes several minutes or more.

Worse yet, even after it succeeds, it's often only a matter of a few days or weeks before macOS seems to need to reverify the app again. (I.e., if the Mac is "whitelisting" the app once it successfully verifies it - that whitelist only lasts for a few days or weeks).

Needless to say, this is ***extremely*** annoying.

I appreciate that MacOs is trying to keep my computer safe from malicious viruses and programs. However, is there a way to ensure that, once whitelisted, a program can ***remain*** whitelisted?

In case it's relevant, I'm running macOS Big Sur (v. 11.2.3), and v. 16.49 of the Microsoft Office for Mac apps.

Comment: same here. I am not experiencing the hangs or the need to force-quit, yet I also always have the verification process running every time.

Comment: How often do you use the Office apps, and which update feed are you on?  If Microsoft Updater changes the binary, the OS is going to try to verify it again.  I can't speak to why it might or might not hang.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Command + Space` and type `terminal` and press enter .

Then type these commands :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/app
```

To find path of your app just simply drag the app to terminal .

Press enter and run this command too .

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /path/to/app
```

Press enter .

Comment: Can you explain what the xattr command does? I'm not familiar with it. I'm hesitant to start typing commands in the terminal without fully understanding what those commands are designed to do.

Comment: @N.W 
With the command line you can use xattr to view and remove extended attributes from a file on the Mac including the application throwing the “Appname. ... The xattr command can also be used to remove the 'application downloaded from the internet' error message on the Mac too.

Comment: This doesn't work in MacOS 13. Both commands generate "Operation not permitted"  though I have used sudo.